# MySql Select max number of rows in contiguous rows

Tags: mysql, hql

I have this table:

```
player_id   goals   date
1           0       16/06
1           1       17/06
1           4       18/06
1           1       19/06
1           0       20/06
```

What I need is to get the number of contiguous matches in which player 1 scored at least a goal.

In this example, the result of the query should be something like:

```
player_id    num_continuous_days
1            3
```

The order of the rows is the date column. Is it possible to achieve this in mysql ?

I'm using Hibernate with HQL for queries, bonus points if it's possible to be done using HQL (I doubt it). I'm willing to use a stored procedure if there is no other way around, and java programming logic as a last measure.

Comment: This link looks like it might work for you. I'd put it as an answer, but I've never tried this and not able to make it match your current issue due to time constraints. Best of luck. http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=803

Comment: You could find some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456857/selecting-continuous-block-of-records-in-mysql

Comment: What is your desired output if a player has multiple contiguous matches within a given time period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sql
SELECT player_id, COUNT(*) num_continuous_days
  FROM
(
  SELECT player_id, goals, date, IF(goals = 0, @n := @n + 1, @n) g
    FROM Table1, (SELECT @n := 0) n
   ORDER BY player_id, date
) q
 WHERE goals > 0
 GROUP BY player_id, g
```

Output:

```
| PLAYER_ID | NUM_CONTINUOUS_DAYS |
-----------------------------------
|         1 |                   3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e0c4/10)** demo

Comment: I reworked it a little in order to only get the max number of days. Works perfectly ! Thanks !