# Searching for continuous range of numbers, while ignoring gaps <= 5

Tags: mysql, sql, range, partitioning

I am trying to find continuous ranges of numeric values from a dataset in MySQL. However, "gaps" in the range smaller than 5 should be ignored. Below is my current code (which works up to some point), split is smaller parts for convenience.

`dataset` contains a "thetime" and "number" column (both numeric). The final goal is to get all the ranges of "thetime" associated with number > 200.

(1) First I select the "gaps" in my dataset, by selecting every "thetime" that has number <= 200.

```
drop temporary table if exists tmp_gaps;
create temporary table tmp_gaps as 
    (select thetime
    from `dataset` 
    where number <= 200);
```

(2) I'm partitioning these found gaps in ranges, according to the method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456857/selecting-continuous-block-of-records-in-mysql).

```
drop temporary table if exists tmp_gaps_withdelta;
create temporary table tmp_gaps_withdelta as
    (select min(thetime) as start, max(thetime) as theend, max(thetime) - min(thetime) + 1 as delta
        from (select thetime, @curRow := @curRow + 1 as row_number
            from tmp_gaps v
                join (select @curRow := 0) w) v
        group by thetime - row_number);
```

(3) Now, I'm trying filter the gaps <= 5 by joining the orginal `dataset` table with `tmp_gaps_withdelta`. If delta <= 5 or delta is null (meaning there is no entry in `tmp_gaps_withdelta` corresponding with the original "thetime" in `dataset`), I consider "thetime" part of a range, and it gets accepted in `db_tmp_ranges`.

```
drop temporary table if exists db_tmp_ranges;
create temporary table db_tmp_ranges as 
    (select 
        case
            when gaps.delta is null 
                or gaps.delta <= 5 then edm.thetime
            else null
        end as thetime
    from `dataset` edm
        left join tmp_gaps_withdelta gaps on edm.thetime >= gaps.start
            and edm.thetime < gaps.start + gaps.delta);
```

Up to this point, everything works as expected. I now have a large set of "thetime" values where "number" from the original table is > 200. The data can be divided into ranges, without gaps <= 5. When I select some data from `db_tmp_ranges`, I'm getting what I'm expecting.

(4) The plan now is to partition, the same way as in (2).

```
select *
from
    (select min(thetime) as start, max(thetime) as theend, max(thetime) - min(thetime) + 1 as delta
    from (select thetime, @curRow := @curRow + 1 as row_number
        from db_tmp_ranges p
            join (select @curRow := 0) r
        where thetime is not null) p
    group by thetime - row_number) q
```

However, the results of this query is absolutely wrong. I honestly don't know where the fault lies, since this way of partitioning in intervals has always worked for me, up till now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: a specific example of how the query reacts:
db_tmp_ranges:

```
...
1393001313
1393001315
1393001316
...
1393001596
1393001597
1393001598
...
```

Result from last query:

```
...
1393001316  1393001319  4
1393001320  1393001591  272
1393001592  1393001595  4
1393001596  1393001881  286
...
```

As you can see, these numbers should be in 1 interval, instead of 4+. After using [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20b23/1/0), it appears the query itself isn't a problem.

I really don't get it. When executing...

```
select * 
from db_tmp_ranges 
where thetime >= 1393001313 
and thetime <= 1393001350 
order by thetime;
```

... I get a normal-looking list of numeric "thetime" values. But somehow the last query doesn't use db_tmp_ranges as it should.

Comment: In what way is your last query result wrong? Can you provide specific examples?

Comment: Yes, my `db_tmp_ranges` table contains 1393001315, 1393001316, 1393001317, 1393001318, 1393001319, 1393001320, ... (continuous range). However, the last query outputs ..., 1393005950-1393006200 (delta 251), **1393001316-1393001319 (delta 4)**, 1393001592-1393001595 (delta 4), ... I'd expected 1393001316-1393001319 to be in a larger range, given the data in 
`db_tmp_ranges`.

Comment: Something's going on behind the scenes that's not evident - I can't replicate the problem with that example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b66a5/2

Comment: @AirThomas You're right. See my last edit: the last query doesn't use `db_tmp_ranges` as it should...

Comment: Are there any duplicates in `db_tmp_ranges`? A single duplicate will split a range, though the resulting ranges will overlap - which isn't the case in the result you show here. And multiple duplicates would cause even more obvious issues. See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6a73/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wondering a while why my last query works in SQL Fiddle, but not on my "real" MySQL database, I've found the solution.

When building the schema in SQL Fiddle, the `thetime` values are inserted **in ascending order**. However, the `thetime` values produced by the query in (3) are in random order. Because `row_number` depends on the order in which the rows are processed, the values **have to be sorted** before feeding them in the last query.

As a result, making the last query work requires the following change:

```
select *
from
    (select min(thetime) as start, max(thetime) as einde, max(thetime) - min(thetime) + 1 as delta
    from (select thetime, @curRow := @curRow + 1 as row_number
        from (select * from db_tmp_ranges where thetime is not null order by thetime) p
            join (select @curRow := 0) r) p
    group by thetime - row_number) q
order by start
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in MySQL is to use variables (in other databases, you can make use of window/analytic functions).  The following assigns a `grp` column to numbers based on your rules:

```
select ds.*,
       @grp := iff(@lastnumber - number <= 5, @grp, @grp + 1) as grp,
       @lastnumber := number
from dataset ds cross join
     (select @lastnumber := -1, @grp := 0) const
order by number;
```

To get the actual sequences:

```
select min(number), max(number), max(number) - min(number) as width,
       count(distinct number) as numNumbers
from (select ds.*,
             @grp := iff(@lastnumber - number <= 5, @grp, @grp + 1) as grp,
             @lastnumber := number
      from dataset ds cross join
           (select @lastnumber := -1, @grp := 0) const
      order by number 
     ) ds
group by grp;
```