# First and last number from random length lists

Tags: php, mysql

OK so I'm trying to get a little tricky thing. I've got a calendar planner in PHP, mySQL in which people are planning their vacations.

In the database it looks like that:
Everyone has sorted lists of vacation days using date(z) - the number of day only.

So in dbase it can looks like that:

```
4
5
6
7
22
23
24
25
52
```

etc.

Output should give a list of all vacation periods with the number of the working days, summed up at the end. So something like that:

```
4-7 (4)
22-25 (2)
52 (1)
------
Sum (7)
```

I've got working function for counting working days so it is up to me but anyone have an idea how to get the first and the last day from each of such a periods?

Comment: In the 'database', could it instead be dates?

Comment: to find the first day left join to self on left.day = right.day +1, and get where right is null ( similar to find the last day )

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to get the first part of your results.

```
select CONCAT(min(day), '-',  max(day), ' (', max(day)-min(day)+1, ')') as result 
FROM 
(
select day, @curRow := @curRow + 1 as row_number, day - @curRow FROM days d JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
) A group by day - row_number;
```

This query will provide the sum:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Sum (', CAST(SUM(results) as CHAR(20)), ')') as results FROM 
(
  select max(day) - min(day) + 1 as results FROM 
  (
  select day, @curRow := @curRow + 1 as row_number, day - @curRow FROM days d JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
  ) A group by day - row_number
) B
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456857/selecting-continuous-block-of-records-in-mysql) for an explanation of how this work.